# Codeigniter routes not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I'm very confused as the documentation for this is very straight forward and simple, I must be missing something.

I have controller that I route to using `routes.php` like so.

`$route['users'] = '/usermanager';`
This works as expected, navigating to `mysite/users` renders my controller.

I have some front end routing to handle different tabs on the user page, so the url can have some sub routes like `/users/management`. The logic for this is all handled on the front end, all I need **is for anything under `/users` to route to the same controller**.

So I write it like so:
`$route['/users/(:any)'] = '/usermanager';`

This fails and I get directed to my 404 page.
I also tried specifying my route explicitly:
`$route['/users/management'] = '/usermanager';`

Still no dice. What am I not understanding about this routing feature.

Heres my full routes.php incase there's something i'm missing:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'EdgeView';
$route['404_override'] = 'PageNotFound';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['view'] = '/';
$route['list'] = '/';
$route['pictorial'] = '/';
$route['certificate'] = '/';
$route['files'] = '/';
$route['about'] = '/';
$route['contact'] = '/';

$route['users'] = '/usermanager';
$route['/users/(:any)'] = '/usermanager';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading slash in your route.

**Change this**

```
$route['/users/(:any)'] = '/usermanager';
```

**to this**

```
$route['users/(:any)'] = 'usermanager';
```

Comment: You should also specify the method to route to: ```$route['users/(:any)'] = 'usermanager/index';```

Comment: Arrrgh, I can't believe I missed that, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the provided .htaccess file by Codeigniter and place it to your root app.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

save that as `.htaccess`

the logic of routing is. your have the **Welcome.php** as a default Controller. If you are going to route your custom Controller do this following.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome' //where execute the Welcome/index
```

Example:

`$route['login'] = 'Auth/login'`

you are just going to call login to your url and it will execute the **Auth/login** dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood, but assuming your controller is `usermanager`, you have to specify where the group should be:

```
$route['/users/(:any)'] = '/usermanager/$1';
```

So, if a request is `/users/testing` would be like `/usermanager/testing`

Comment: This is still not working for me, any route after /users is giving me a 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter Most Of Pepole Used this 3 type of route

//Simple Route

`$route['login'] = 'Login/index';`

//pass route with id or noumber

`$route['product/(:num)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1';`

// pass any route

`$route['product/(:any)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';`

// pass moulte value in route

`$route['product/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';`